# HTTP file upload component - CRC and resume functionality - What are my alternatives?

Tags: http, file-upload, crc

I am looking to upload large files - 40gb+ - to my server, which might be either PHP or ASP.Net. I'm looking for atleast CRC and resume support - I want to know that my file is correct and I want to be able to resume an upload that has been previously disrupted.

This should be pretty straightforward to implement - Simply use a java applet client side to chunk up the file in segments, calculate CRC, ship each segment to server together with the CRC and a position so I can zip it together when I have all partial files.

Also, I could perhaps implement this using a java applet FTP client, which uploads to my server, which might be the more standards compliant way.

HOWEVER, even if my development fingers itch with eagerness to implement this, I have to think about it from a management/effectiveness perspective. So now I am asking you:

Are there any great alternatives out there that already supports what I need? I've googled and found http://upload.thinfile.com/features.php and http://radinks.com/upload/features.php

Neither solution says anything about CRC or file validity checking. Also, I'm not really impressed by the presentation - which leads me to doubt these vendors.

Do you have any suggestions?

Best regards, Max

Answer (score 1):

Demo I made several months ago: http://dnduploader.filkor.org/

As you can see, it's possible to do resumable file uploading with only Javascript. You will find the source of that page on Github..enjoy.

Because we slicing up the files into little 'packets' (we only upload a little 'packet' at a time) so you don't even need to change the php.ini settings. When all the packets are uploaded, the server will merge them (which is only some CPU)

Of course it needs the new  Javascript File API (latest Chrome, Firefox, and it seems IE10 partially supported), but I'm sure this will be the near future of uploading large files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in Flash implementation? I noticed several Flash based upload implementations with progress bar and resume. I didn't check them myself, although I have a similar to your task. Unfortunately neither Applet, not Flash is my options, since my client doesn't allow to install any add-ons on browser and still requires checksum validation and resume.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that current implementations of Flash (runtimes or other flaw, I don't know) attempt to load the complete file into memory, which is not possible in my case, since files needed to be more than 40gb. We ended up rolling our own simple system where we used POST to upload segments, as a java applet.